# Extract 2 groups with grep or awk

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I got this file:

```
<DEALER_ID>1234</DEALER_ID><CODE>O_777</CODE>
<DEALER_ID>7532</DEALER_ID><CODE>O_991</CODE>
```

and I want this output:

```
1234 O_777
7532 O_991
```

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
cat deal | sed 's/<\/DEALER_NAME>/<\/DEALER_NAME>\n/g' | grep -Po "<DEALER_ID>.*</CODE>" | grep -Po "\d*"
```

Just the first column

Comment: Consider using a XML parser

Comment: Don't use `awk` for `XML` parsing

Comment: Please listen to above comments, if you cannot in situations that your server doest not have xml parsers, then `sed -r 's/^[^>]+>([^<]+).*>([^<]+).*/\1 \2/'`

Comment: Guys, please. Don't just tell him to use some tool, recommend him some particular tool and show how it works. I - for one - 'd be interested to see if some tool I don't know of would be easier to use than sed or awk for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3, $(NF-2)}' f
1234 O_777
7532 O_991
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/<[^>]*>/," ")&&$1=$1' file
1234 O_777
7532 O_991
```

Explained:

```
gsub(/<[^>]*>/," ")  # replace <.*> with a space
&&                   # and 
$1=$1                # rebuild the record to remove excess space
                     # implicit output. won't print lines without <.*>
```

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting.